# how to avoid image frame counting, in counting contours?

Tags: python, opencv

how to avoid image frame counting, in counting contours?
(opencv python)

[there have 6 contours with image frame.i need avoid image frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1SXL.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV as a parameter of threshold function.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('./tmp.png')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
img = cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

print("num contours = {}".format(len(contours)))
cv2.imwrite("./contours.png", img)
```

result image:
[image]